# Component not updating after update to embedded schema field

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1

We are having trouble getting components to update to the new schema after changing one of the fields on an embedded schema from required to optional.  Opening & saving the component does not have any affect.  I tried control-f5 in case browser cache was the issue.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We had the same issue. I have fixed it by modifying the TCM54 config file. It is a one time change and it works very well. I did this in Dev environments and *life is much better for all Developers post this change* :) I did not do in other environments since it impacts all users because I have set max age to the bare minimum value and then schemas are not cached

I've set the max-age attributes to "1" (it is in seconds) for the schemas in TCM54.config file under `%TRIDION_HOME%\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration`:

```
  <cfg:cache implementation="Tridion.ContentManager.Schema" max-age="1" />
  <cfg:cache implementation="Tridion.ContentManager.ListSchemas" max-age="1" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I would try to do it in a different browser, As Tridion is heavily cached at client and sever ends based on so many things and User-Agents is one of them.

Ctrl+F5 will force browser to clear out the cache and request a new from the server, But server may ignore the no-cache header and serve a server side cached page. So Ctrl+F5 could return an old version of the page if the server ignores the no-cache header.

Ctrl+F5 never works with tridion if you want to reload a Extended GUI Resources(like CSS, JS, Images). The ultimate way to clear out tridion cache is to increase the "modification" attribute of "server" element in "system.config". The file could be found at "%tridionInsatallDir%\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration" on the CMS Server.

Comment: As far as I understand (as [explained by @FrankvanPuffelen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14668866/395495)) the `modification` attribute impacts Javascript and CSS and some images. Updating the modication doesn't impact Schemas and Components.

Comment: Yeah the "Updated GUI" was not the right term to use. I've updated the answer, Thanks @AlvinReyes.